# Make Nemo handle the desktop in (Mint) Xfce

Tags: xfce, desktop, thunar, nemo

For the purpose detailed below uninstalling Thunar is not a solution. The   behavior described below stays the same if Thunar is uninstalled. So, **it is not Thunar as such that handles the Xfce desktop.** So, when here I say "Thunar desktop" or "Thunar icons" (in relation to desktop icons) that should mean the Xfce desktop handler, whatever that is.

---

For various reasons I want to use Nemo as default file manager in Xfce (Mint 19.2). Just installing Nemo and making it the preferred file manager in `exo-preferred-applications` is not making Nemo handle the desktop too.

So, trying to make Nemo handle the desktop, I know that the needed command is `nemo-desktop`.

Simply running that at startup doesn't make it happen though, as seen when running the command in terminal

```
** (nemo-desktop:9781): WARNING **: 16:50:30.626: Desktop already managed by another application, skipping desktop setup.
To change this, modify org.nemo.desktop 'ignored-desktop-handlers'.
```

At this point `nemo-desktop` is **not** listed in running applications.

Going to dconf Editor, I have added `['thunar']` there. (The same effect as `['org.xfce.FileManager']` it seems; `org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons` which is specifically described as intended to "allow Nemo to manage the desktop" is  marked as "Deprecated", and changing its value makes no difference.)  At this point, if in (`xfdesktop-settings`) *Desktop -> Icons -> Appearance -> Icon type* is set to *File/launcher icons*, **after restarting session** the desktop shows desktop icons twice (once through Nemo-desktop, once through Xfce/Thunar desktop), with the Nemo icons on top, while those of Xfce/Thunar are not accessible.

This mix is bad, but at least confirms that `nemo-desktop` is running, as seen in the System Monitor list, and can be temporarily rectified by setting *Desktop -> Icons -> Appearance -> Icon type* to *none*. This gives me what I want, but only till the end of the session: all icons go away (as set in `xfdesktop-settings`) **after restarting session**. (This works for me sort of, as I rarely log out or restart, but simply suspend.)

**Only if *Desktop -> Icons -> Appearance -> Icon type* is already set to *File/launcher icons* during session startup do the Nemo icons appear on the desktop. -- Nemo follows the `xfdesktop-settings` that are in place at session startup, while changes made during session only affect Xfce/Thunar icons.** (Nemo-desktop icons stay visible until logout even if `xfdesktop-settings` says differently.)

The solution would be to set *Desktop -> Icons -> Appearance -> Icon type* to *File/launcher icons* but to completely stop Xfce-desktop-manager ([whichever that is, because it's not Thunar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543492/341192)) from handling the desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as said in the question, Thunar removal is not needed. (If it was removed, it can be re-installed; in Mint it's `sudo apt install thunar mint-meta-xfce thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-media-tags-plugin thunar-volman xfce4-places-plugin`.)

The whole problem is related to [identifying the Xfce desktop manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543492/341192).

I have received an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543558/341192) to that question: it's `xfdesktop`.

It must run in Xfce in order to have a proper desktop;  it shouldn't be stopped (with`xfdesktop --quit`) as suggested in the question, or the desktop loses wallpaper and compositing. But all problems mentioned in the question disappear as everything falls into place once `xfdesktop` program is specified correctly in `gsettings`: Nemo-desktop is the desktop manager associated with Nemo; it checks whether other desktop managers are running; if the case, nemo-desktop stops, except when such managers are specified in `gsettings` (maybe with **dconf Editor**) under `org.nemo.desktop ignored-desktop-handlers`.

So:

- in terminal do `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop ignored-desktop-handlers ['xfdesktop']`
- in `xfdesktop-settings` ('Desktop') go to *Icons -> Appearance -> Icon type* and set it to *none*
- in 'Session and Startup' (`xfce4-session-settings`), 'Application autostart', add `nemo-desktop`
- restart session

---

Other useful settings for Nemo in Xfce:

- integrate with Thunar bulk rename: in Nemo, *Edit > Preferences > Behavior > Bulk rename*, enter `thunar --bulk-rename`
- add custom actions with `filemanager-actions` (Filemanager-Actions Configurations Tool); details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/925128)

Comment: `['xfdesktop']` must be in quotes: `"['xfdesktop']"`