# What is the Xfce desktop manager - given it's not Thunar? (What is the Xfce equivalent of nemo-desktop)?

Tags: xfce, desktop, file-manager, thunar, nemo

Trying to [make Nemo take over the desktop in Mint Xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543468/341192) I found that very difficult, even if Thunar is uninstalled. Therefore, it is not Thunar by itself that handles the desktop (the icon desktop I mean), but something within the Xfce desktop environment different from the file manager Thunar. After removing Thunar though, some desktop context menu actions stop working, like creating folder or document, with an error about `org.xfce.FileManager`.

[image]

`nemo-desktop` is the Nemo equivalent, not dependent on the Cinnamon desktop. What is that for Xfce if not Thunar?

Comment: `xfdesktop` https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By request, my comment posted as an answer: `xfdesktop` [docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/start](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/start)

Unfortunately, I don't have any directly pertinent details, as I've never pursued replacement of `xfdesktop` with a file manager's desktop handling functionality or anything else.

I *did* do a brief search of `replace "xfdesktop"` on DuckDuckGo and found (four pages deep in the search results) a page providing evidence that xfdesktop ***can*** be replaced. See the section of the page [Tips, Tricks and Howtos | Xfce Wiki](https://xfce.fandom.com/wiki/Tips,_Tricks_and_Howtos) entitled "How to use ROX to manage your desktop in order to have desktop icons". Don't know if that's of any help, but there it is.

Comment: In fact I have found a solution to the linked question about Nemo-desktop taking over he desktop in place of the Xfce desktop manager, thanks to you. `xfdesktop` simply needs to be specified in dconf Editor under `org.nemo.desktop ignored-desktop-handlers`, but it needs not (nor should be) stopped or removed. See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543557/341192).

Comment: Excellent! I use Caja in Xfce, so I'm definitely holding on to a that link to try shifting desktop management to Caja at some point.