# Could not find "/home/user/%U" after changing default file manager

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, thunar, nemo

I'm running Mint 20 XFCE, I kinda didn't liked the default Thunar file manager, so I installed Nemo.

**What I tried**

I set as default file manager nemo from the preferred applications settings and also edited the command for file manager by:

- Searched file manager in the whisker menu.
- Right click --> Edit Application.
- Changed the command to nemo %U.
- `sudo apt purge thunar`

**The problem:**

When I click on the Home directory icon on the desktop:

> **could not find "/home/user/%U"**
>
> Please check the spelling and try again.

When I tried moving/copying/opening a file from the desktop to other directories in `/home`:

> Error moving file /home/user/Desktop/xyz.pdf (same with folders too.)
>
> : No such file or directory

How to solve the issue?

Comment: The problem may be related to getting Nemo to manage the desktop, resolved in the post [Make Nemo handle the desktop in (Mint) Xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543468/make-nemo-handle-the-desktop-in-mint-xfce).

Comment: Could you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Wasn't meant to be an answer, just a speculative comment. Did it solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked you to write your comment as an aswer.